# Webdriver - Element can be located properly, but cannot interact. Firefox only

Tags: java, html, webdriver

Here is the code:

```
<td class="padding-removed" style="width: 86px; background-color: rgb(232, 245, 209);">
    <ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows">
        <li><a class="sf-with-ul">Take&nbsp;Actions</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="action-link">Action 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="action-link" href="/property/edit/105645">Action 2</a></li>
            </ul>  
        </li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

I have the problem of interacting with the item "`Take&nbsp;Actions`" now. I can locate it without any problems, it can be confirmed by getting it's text and location etc. But I cannot interact with it, like clicking, moving mouse over etc. I've tried everything I can, like webdriver performing actions and Javascript simulation etc. The problem is FF only, Chrome and IE work well.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Show us the code that works with everyone but firefox. We can only help you effectively with them.

Comment: Tried FF from very old (3.6) to current one (21). Webdriver 25 - 32

Comment: Nothing special in my code. I've tried with xpath, css and linktext to locate it, each of them works, no any exceptions, but just cannot interact, like click and mouseover etc., nothing happens when performing the actions, no errors and exceptions at all. Can you please take a look at the html code, I'm afraid if anything special to FF here. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, FF could potentially have native action, locating or timing issues. We can't identify the issue without your code. It should be just a simple tweak for your code, if you don't want to provide it, we can only guess what went wrong.

Comment: It's hard for me to give you my code, they're in the different packages/classes. I'm using the page factory. The problem occurred after the html code got changed. It worked well before these changes.

Comment: Here is the previous html code:
<td class="padding-removed" style="width: 86px; background-color: rgb(232, 245, 209);">
 <ul id="dropdown_menu_action_menu_105645" class="drop-down ">
  <li id="action_menu_105645" class="">
   <div id="dropdown_menu_link_action_menu_105645" class="link_container">
    <a class="dropdown_title" href="javascript://">Take&nbsp;Actions</a>
   </div>
   <ul>
    <li><a id="undefined" href="javascript://">Action 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="undefined" href="javascript://">Action 2</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</td>

Comment: Never mind. It works now after upgrading Selenium to 2.33.0 which just came out today :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `by.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Take') and contains(text(),'Action')]")`